# Is there a way to throw custom exception without Exception class

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

Is there any way in C# (i.e. in .NET) to throw a custom exception but without writing all the code to define your own exception class derived from `Exception`?

I am thinking something similar you have for example in Oracle PL/SQL where you can simply write

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'An arbitary error message');
```

at any place.

Comment: You can add custom properties to a custom exception class, so couldn't you just make one custom exception class, then add an Enum for the "type" of exception?

Comment: If `throw new Exception("An arbitary error message");` won't work for you, it might be a good idea to extend a question to explain why.

Comment: No, There isn't and there shouldn't be.

Comment: @ZoharPeled What's your rationale for saying that?

Comment: @mason: My rational is very simple: Exceptions carry a lot more information then just a simple message. they carry the stack trace, they can carry an inner exception, etc. PL/SQL raise error does not. Another reason is that raising an error message without using an Exception object goes agains the normal exception pattern, and .Net does not provide a try...catch mechanism for that. (

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
throw new Exception("A custom message for an application specific exception");
```

Not good enough?

You could also throw a more specific exception if it's relevant.  For example,

```
throw new AuthenticationException("Message here");
```

or

```
throw new FileNotFoundException("I couldn't find your file!");
```

could work.

Note that you should probably **not** `throw new ApplicationException()`, per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The major draw back of not customizing Exception is that it will be more difficult for callers to catch - they won't know if this was a general exception or one that's specific to your code without doing some funky inspection on the exception.Message property.  You could do something as simple as this:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    MyException(int severity, string message) : base(message)
    {
        // do whatever you want with severity
    }
}
```

to avoid that.

**Update**: Visual Studio 2015 now offers some automatic implementation of Exception extension classes - if you open the *Quick Actions and Refactoring Menu* with the cursor on the `: Exception`, just tell it to "Generate All Constructors".

Comment: You shouldn't use the `ApplicationException` class, see the remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ApplicationException is effectively deprecated.

Comment: This is not a "Custom" exception as the OP asked. However, I'm more interested in understanding this statement: "_Note that you should probably not throw new Exception(), as that can cause other problems._" - can you explain further?

Comment: Sorry about that, got them mixed up!  Switched around now.

Comment: @MetroSmurf think about it, its an exception without *any information what-so-ever* about what happened. On top of that, its impossible to handle without handling every exception (`catch Exception` instead of `catch SpecificException`).

Comment: I did not notice (although it is obvious), that `throw new Exception` is overloaded and that you can pass custom error message.

Comment: Don't throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions#things-to-avoid-when-throwing-exceptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types

Answer (score 12):

The `Exception` class is not an `abstract`, and like most of the exceptions defined in .NET, takes a `string message` in one of the constructor overloads - you can therefore use an existing exception type, but with a customized message.

```
throw new Exception("Something has gone haywire!");
throw new ObjectDisposedException("He's Dead, Jim");
throw new InvalidCastException(
    $"Damnit Jim I'm a {a.GetType().Name}, not a {b.GetType().Name}!");
```

Because this uses exception types that are known, it makes it easier for thrid parties to extend your libraries as well, since they don't need to look for `MyArbitraryException` in `catch` statements.

Comment: I'm going to have to remember that `InvalidCastException`!

Comment: @David this is correct but all of the **Exceptions** should be of the type **DwightSchruteException("..")** LOL

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to create custom Exceptions in c# is using a generic class. This reduces the lines of code dramatically if you need to create much exceptions (i.e. if you need to distinguish between them in your unit tests).

First create a simple class called `CustomException<T>`:

```
public class CustomException<T> : Exception where T : Exception
{
    public CustomException() { }
    public CustomException(string message) : base(message){ }
    public CustomException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException){ }
    public CustomException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context){ }
}
```

You can override as many constructors and methods as you want (or need) to. In order to create new Exception types just add new one-liner classes:

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception { }
public class SomeOtherException : Exception { }
```

If you want to raise your custom exception use:

```
throw new CustomException<MyCustomException>("your error description");
```

This keeps your Exception code simple and allows you to distinguish between those exceptions:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(CustomException<MyCustomException> ex)
{
    // handle your custom exception ...
}
catch(CustomException<SomeOtherException> ex)
{
    // handle your other exception ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - no.

There is a good reason for enforcing the inheritance of custom exceptions; people need to be able to handle them. If you could throw your custom exception without having a type, people wouldn't be able to catch that exception type.

If you don't want to write a custom exception, use an existing exception type.

Answer (score 3):

You can just throw one of the exceptions that is available in .NET:

```
throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "original");
```

Or more generic:

```
throw new ApplicationException("File storage capacity exceeded.");
```